# Measuring compositions using peak heights or FWHM?

Tags: spectroscopy, statistics, x-rays

Let's say I have a simple X-ray spectrum, consisting of peaks corresponding to emission lines. How do I determine the percentage-wise composition of the source? Is it by taking the heights of the peaks, summing them, and then dividing one peak height by the total to get that peak's composition? Or is there something more complicated involved by taking the FWHM? What can the FWHM be used for?

Comment: It turns out that is a really difficult problem, particularly if you want precision in the composition.

Comment: Okay, let's say I'm not interested in a composition measurement. What quantities of interest can be obtained from the FWHM?

Comment: See [this link](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_parameter_is_more_relevant_between_XRD_peak_net_height_and_its_net_area) for a discussion of the problem.